# Can't find ant in the Android SDK

Tags: android

I'm working my way through APress's Beginning Android 2 and I've made it all the way to chapter 3, where we build a skeleton app. The book tells me to compile my application by typing "ant" in the command line, but my pc doesn't know what "ant" is yet. I checked in the SDK files and it looks like it wasn't included with the Android SDK. Does anybody know where ant is?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry for not being more explicit in the book on this point.

Comment: Don't worry. You included the disclaimer at the beginning that said that I would need to know Java before starting. This is obviously a book for people with more experience than me but I'm going to see how much of it I can power through anyway.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ant isn't included with the Android SDK. I suggest you get it from the [official site](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi).

Comment: and if you want to use it from command line - do not forget to add <ant_home>/bin to PATH

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for that - I have missed that detail in the past.

Comment: If you're working on a Linux machine, most distros have an ant package you can simply install (e.g. "apt-get install ant" on Debian/Ubuntu or "yum install ant" on RPM-based distros).

Comment: The first link is dead!

Comment: For OSX try `brew install ant` 
Install http://brew.sh if you haven't already, it's excellent.

Comment: There was only one broken link in Jim's reply. Sahuagin, you didn't need to delete the other link. And you say you fixed a link but you did not. I submitted an edit that just fixed the one broken link preserving his post. You though gave one link and removed the rest of his post. That's not so good. Jim perhaps you'd like to put your post back! (just correct the one broken link)  Correct link is  http://developer.android.com/tools/workflow/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Ant is tool to build projects from commondline and it is different tool. It's not android specific. So if your are using a Debian-based/Ubuntu machine you can install it by

```
sudo apt-get install ant
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit odd, but even I install `brew install ant` and rebuild / re-sync the gradle file, it still doesn't work, so I restarted my Intellij and it started to download the `ant1.7` again from maven.