# How to build app from command line with ant?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to build android project from command line.
I tried to run this line in the command line:

```
C:\Users\davida\workspace_8\MyApp>ant debug
```

And this is the answer:

```
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

And I tried the android developers http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html, 
with no luck.

First, how can I know if I have installed ant on my computer?
(if I navigate thru eclipse tool bar to window -> preferences I have window with Ant Menu on the left contains "Editor" and "Runtime") Is it mean that the ant installed and I can build with it from the command line??

I can debug and run with emulator and my device thru eclipse.

After searching I read that I need to set java variables so I did:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_01
```

my OS: win7

Well.. I am lost any help??
If someone have step by step sample I will be glad.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to ensure that the `ant` build system is installed ([as it is not bundled with the Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577638/700926)) - you can download `ant` from here: http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi.

Secondly, you must ensure that `ant` has been added to your `PATH`.

Comment: Here is an example how to add the command to the PATH variable:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150729183638/http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html