# Android Studio SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I am getting this error:

> SDK Platform Tools component is missing

when I run: > ant clean debug.
This is following setup steps for an android project and I am very new to android.

Searching I find that I should be able to click the SDK icon in the toolbar, which I see but it is disabled. I'm assuming the SDK library is missing or a configuration is pointing to the incorrect place.

I have this [standalone SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) as I am not using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Ant isn't included with the SDK, and you'll need to get it separately.

Check the SO thread here: [Can't find ant in the Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577578/cant-find-ant-in-the-android-sdk)