# Cannot build cordova.jar because cannot find /tools/ant/build.xml

Tags: android, xml, cordova, ant, cordova-plugins

Currently, I need to build cordova.jar to using CordovaWebView at my android project. But I'am failed to build Cordova.jar from cordova-android project, because

> /tools/ant/build.xml

Not found at my Android SDK. And because of 1 line code [Build.xml](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/build.xml%22build.xml%22) at project cordova/framework there is

```
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
```

needed that build.xml, how I replace it to my ant own.

I know ant was [not included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577578/cant-find-ant-in-the-android-sdk%22not%20included%22) on Android SDK now. How I can create Cordova.jar or download latest cordova.jar ?

Comment: Have you tried removing android and re-adding android to the project?

Comment: @KodyR. I build it before adding to my android project. I use cli 'ant jar' to build *.jar

Comment: any update on this?